# Socket.io Cross-Origin Resource Sharing Issue

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, websocket, socket.io, socketserver

We have our socket server hosted on AWS and it is connected with 4 URLs. The code base hasn't been changed for like 9 months but recently I'm getting an error.

**The error:**

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https:something' from origin 'https://something' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

GET https://something net::ERR_FAILED 522

**The socket server CORS setting:**

```
    cors: [{
        origin: process.env.CORS,
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }, {
        origin: process.env.CORS2,
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }, {
        origin: process.env.CORS3,
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    },{
        origin: process.env.CORS4,
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    },{
        origin: process.env.CORS5,
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
    }]
});
```

We are using "socket.io": "^4.0.1"

Not sure how to fix this issue

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by rebooting the AWS server instance